# How to change theme of a fragment programmatically in android

Tags: android

I have a MainActivity where i show different fragments on button click. But for one particular fragment, I have to change the theme where toolbar has different color. I checked many posts and i came across the code,"setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)". I cannot apply this in MainActivity, because it will be applied to all Fragments. So how to set theme for a specific fragment.
.

Comment: you need to write your startActivity in your run() method

Answer (score 0):

Run the prefs sentences into run() method

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
pref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    editor = pref.edit();
    String userid=pref.getString("driver_id","");

    Log.e("userid",userid);
    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(userid))
    {
        String usertype=pref.getString("userType","");
        if(usertype.equals("customer"))
        {
            Intent customer=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, NavigationActivity.class);
            startActivity(customer);
        }
        else if(usertype.equals("driver"))
        {

            Intent driver=new Intent(this, DriverNavigationActivity.class);
            startActivity(driver);
            finish();


        }
    }
    else
    {
        Intent walk=new Intent(SplashActivity.this,SigninActivity.class);
        startActivity(walk);
    }

        }
    }, 2000);
```

Comment: Create `SplashActivity` and you will have your `MainActivity` by default.